# Uniformity test on a large set using scipy.stats.kstest

Tags: python, random, statistics, cryptography, numpy-random

I'm playing around with some hardware entropy creation. I'm using electronic sensors to sample the environment, using A2D with between 12-16 bits of resolution. I'm hypothesizing that the lower-order bits from these readings contain enough noise and real-world entropy to be effectively "random" - at least enough to seed a PRNG.

My approach is to take the samples and progressively truncate them, chopping off the most significant bits, until the results start looking uniformly distributed. And then over time I can pack these lower-order "random" bits together to make larger "random" integer values.

Setting aside the *validity* of this approach (please), my real problem is evaluating the "randomness" of the data. More precisely, measuring the uniformity of the distribution of the truncated samples. Again, I'm shaving off higher-order bits progressively till the resulting values look more-or-less uniformly distributed... but having trouble coming up with a way to statistically measure the uniformity, even roughly.

I first tried the Chi-Square approach, but apparently this [doesn't handle large data sets well](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/440371/chi-square-test-with-high-sample-size-and-unbalanced-data)? (I've got 10k samples per sensor.)

Then I moved on to the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test, trying to compare my data set to the uniform distribution. The `kstest()` method expects floating point values between 0 and 1. I can normalize my integer samples by dividing each value by the max value (2^bits) to fit this requirement, but when the bit-width gets low, the values are still going to be very discrete (for example, with truncated width of 2 bits, there will only be values 0.0, 0.25, 0.5 and 0.75).

I decided to test this with the following code:

```python
import random
import math
from scipy.stats import kstest 

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    samples = 1000
    random.seed(0)
    print('samples: {}'.format(samples))

    for bits in range(1, 16):
        max_val = (2 ** bits) - 1
        obs = []
        for i in range(samples):
            int_val = random.randint(0, max_val)
            obs.append(float(int_val) / max_val)
        stat, p = kstest(obs, 'uniform')
        print('{:3} bits : p={}'.format(bits, p))
```

I'm not sure how to interpret the results. It seems to show that the algorithm doesn't work well for low bit counts, but the results still vary a *lot* as you add bits. If you comment out the `seed(0)` line, you'll see p values vary wildly.

Here's the values for seed zero:

```
samples: 1000
  1 bits : p=1.1061100101127136e-234
  2 bits : p=5.3150572686544944e-62
  3 bits : p=4.4512615958880796e-14
  4 bits : p=0.0006808631612435064
  5 bits : p=0.14140010855519292
  6 bits : p=0.20814194572050182
  7 bits : p=0.49167945198677787
  8 bits : p=0.496368700963041
  9 bits : p=0.8532040305202887
 10 bits : p=0.6961716307178489
 11 bits : p=0.41693384153785173
 12 bits : p=0.8484539510181118
 13 bits : p=0.16853102951415444
 14 bits : p=0.8175442993699236
 15 bits : p=0.30957048529568965
```

My questions:

1. Is there a better way to evaluate the uniform-distribution-ness of a range of integer values (that is, a range from zero to some power of 2), particularly in the case of fewer bits per sample (1-4)? I'm looking for some python code that will digest a bunch of samples and give me some quantitative and meaningful evaluation of how *uniform* the distribution *appears* to be.
2. Am I applying the K-S test properly here? I would think that as the numbers of bits-per-sample goes up, the resulting normalized values would appear more continuous (less discrete), which I further assume would make the p-value "get better". But after 5-6 bits, it doesn't seem to matter - it seems to wander all over the place. So I'm wondering if I'm doing it right or maybe misunderstanding what I'm measuring.

Comment: Okay... I think the key here was that I was feeding `kstest()` a [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) (in the form of a "normalized histogram"), not a [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).

Answer (score 1):

K-S test (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)) is the distance between your sampled (aka empirical) CDF and ideal (aka model) CDF. CDF there is cumulative distribution function.

For uniform distribution CDF is very [simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution).

```
def uniCDF(x):
    if x < 0.0:
        return 0.0
    if x > 1.0:
        return 1.0
    return x
```

So make huge array of your samples (whatever way you got them), and call kstest with something like

```
kstest(samples, uniCDF)
```

and see how it is

Comment: Thanks for this... the key point here is that I need to give `kstest` a CDF, not  a PDF.

Comment: @cbp2 Yes, absolutely! KS test is all about CDF-vs-CDF, as I wrote

Answer (score 1):

The other answer posted wasn't really the solution, but it *did* highlight what I was doing wrong. I wasn't using `kstest()` correctly. It wants a CDF, not a PDF - and I was effectively giving it a PDF.

Here's the updated test code:

```python
import random
import math
from scipy.stats import kstest
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    samples = 1000
    random.seed(0)
    print('samples: {}'.format(samples))

    for bits in range(1, 16):
        max_val = 2 ** bits
        obs = []
        for i in range(samples):
            obs.append(np.random.randint(max_val))

        count, bins_count = np.histogram(obs, bins='auto')
        pdf = count / sum(count)
        cdf = np.cumsum(pdf)
        stat, p = kstest(cdf, 'uniform')
        print('{:3} bits : p={}'.format(bits, p))
```

This gave the following results:

```
samples: 1000
  1 bits : p=0.002865197735232071
  2 bits : p=0.3578313345590808
  3 bits : p=0.9379905983222332
  4 bits : p=0.9492173736681953
  5 bits : p=0.9990666389407863
  6 bits : p=0.9991168380270133
  7 bits : p=0.9884493351721916
  8 bits : p=0.9979292700419209
  9 bits : p=0.9984858969520626
 10 bits : p=0.9927394764400753
 11 bits : p=0.9991880763266139
 12 bits : p=0.9998600940511319
 13 bits : p=0.9971921916005222
 14 bits : p=0.9996272719319321
 15 bits : p=0.999437259974763
```

That at least makes more sense to me.

So it looks like the K-S test might work on data down to 3 bits or so. That will probably have to do.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that for 2 bits you could simply count the number in each "bin" and each should be "close" for 1/4 and for 1 bit, close to 1/2. You can decide what your cut-off should be on "close". I don't know statistics well enough to tell you what the cutoff should be at that level.

Note that when you get down to that level I would probably just use a pseudo-random number generator with nicely measured properties (e.g. Mersenne Twister) rather than trying to get bits from the entropy source, as factors you weren't expecting (that might cause long bursts of 1s or 0s) might cause your entropy source to be less "random". If I recall correctly, the hardware implementations of "true randoms" used in Intel processors do something like that. They use a PRNG and some tests to see if "reseeding" is necessary and then they use the collected bits from the entropy source to reseed it. But by using a well-tested PRNG, they get nice distributions and the entropy source is used only to make certain that it is actually "random" and not "too" predictable over long stretches.